# Haskell Data instance for opaque data type

Tags: haskell, ffi

I'm writing an open source patch to use a font library, or rather the haskell bindings to a font library in C (FTGL).
I'm pointing to the Font type in one of the data structures, which is defined as follows:

```
type Font = Ptr Font_Opaque
data Font_Opaque
```

Unfortunately, to fit into the data structure of the library I'm patching, this type needs to be an instance of [Data](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html).  Ptr already is, but Font_Opaque obviously isn't, so the compiler complains.

As it's an opaque type I'm not sure how to proceed ... how to implement *Data Font_Opaque* in a more or less sensible way?  Is there a sensible way?

Comment: You could try `deriving instance Data Font_Opaque` (enable the `StandaloneDeriving` extension first) and then (if GHC can derive) look at the instance with `-ddump-deriv`.

Answer (score 5):

As the comment by András Kovács suggests, using the StandaloneDeriving language extension

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving -#}
```

and then:

```
deriving instance Data Font_Opaque
```

did the trick, at least where the compiler is concerned. I'll report back if this affects the program in any way.  Thanks!